# CS0103: The name 'Tridion' does not exist in the current context

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

**Tridion 20ll SP1**

While Installing CDS at step 'the HTTP Upload server role as a .NET Web site' we are facing various issues.

After following all the steps in the installation guide, we get the error "CS0103: The name 'Tridion' does not exist in the current context" while browsing the httpupload.aspx page.

As per guide, the expected output should be 'SDL Tridion ASPX Upload Page'.

Could you please help?

Comment: Hi All, This is now resolved. The Bin folder was missing some namespaces. We corrected this.

Comment: I assume you mean it was missing some assemblies (e.g. Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll)

Comment: Peter, if you answer it you will get your easiest rep points ever :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your Web App contains all of the correct DLLs, and a `config` folder with the correct configuration XML files, and a `lib` folder with all the correct JARS. Most likely you are missing some of the Tridion DLLs like `Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll`.